# Observables and subscribing angular 2

Tags: angular, observable, subscribe

I know there are other posts on it but those answers just aren't clicking for me and the docs aren't either sadly. I am really struggling to use observables and subscribe to them. What I am trying to to is update and array in one component and display that in another, that isn't a parent or child component. If someone just be so kind to break it down in the simplest terms thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a common service that you can inject in both the components. The service needs to have 2 methods to return the array and another to update the array.

Sample Syntax of service:

```
 getComments() : Observable<Comment[]> {
     return this.http.get(this.commentsUrl)
     // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
     .map((res:Response) => res.json())
     //...errors if any
     .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
 }
```

Sample syntax of component:

```
loadComments() {
    // Get all comments
     this.commentService.getComments()
                       .subscribe(
                           comments => this.comments = comments, //Bind to view
                            err => {
                                // Log errors if any
                                console.log(err);
                            });
}
```